# How to sort an array in php by the incoming $_REQUEST["id"]

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Here is my php code

```
//coming id is identical to one of the list
if(isset($_REQUEST["id"])) {
    $id = intval($_REQUEST["id"]); 
}

$arr["array"] = array(
    0=>array("ID"=>"1", "NAME"=>"aaa"),
    1=>array("ID"=>"2", "NAME"=>"bbb"),
    2=>array("ID"=>"3", "NAME"=>"ccc"),
    3=>array("ID"=>"4", "NAME"=>"ddd")
);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($arr); echo "</pre>";
```

result:
    Array
    (
        [array] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [ID] => 1
                        [NAME] => aaa
                    )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [ID] => 2
                        [NAME] => bbb
                    )
                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [ID] => 3
                        [NAME] => ccc
                    )
                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [ID] => 4
                        [NAME] => ddd
                    )
            )
    )

for example index.php?id=3, how can I get a result like this:

```
Array
(
    [array] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 3
                    [NAME] => ccc
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 1
                    [NAME] => aaa
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 2
                    [NAME] => bbb
                )
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 4
                    [NAME] => ddd
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: You could make it easier on yourself if you used the ID as the array key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
foreach ($arr['array'] as $key => $val)
{
        if ($val['ID'] == $id)
        {
            unset($arr['array'][$key]);

            $arr['array'] = array_merge(array($val), $arr['array']);

            break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

untested, but i think its ok

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["id"])) {
    $id = intval($_REQUEST["id"]); 
}

$arr["array"] = array(
    0=>array("ID"=>"1", "NAME"=>"aaa"),
    1=>array("ID"=>"2", "NAME"=>"bbb"),
    2=>array("ID"=>"3", "NAME"=>"ccc"),
    3=>array("ID"=>"4", "NAME"=>"ddd")
);
$sorted = Array();
$sortedIndex = 1; // preserve index=0 for the match id
$found = false;
for($a=0;$a<count($arr['array']);$a++){
    if($arr['array'][$a]['ID'] == $id){
        sorted['array'][0] = $arr['array'][$a];
        $found = true;
    }else{
        $sorted['array'][$sortedIndex] = $arr['array'][$a];
        ++$sortedIndex;
    }

    if($a+1 > count($arr['array']) && !$found){
        //id not found in data array...
        echo "ID not found!";
        break;
    }
}//for loop

echo "<pre>"; print_r($sorted); echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: You're looping over `count($arr)` while using that to index `$arr['array']`.

Comment: yes you are right, noted and changed code count($arr['array'])
thank you